# openCV mac OSX suggested webcam

Tags: macos, opencv, webcam

Does anyone have a recommendation for a web cam to be used on a mac with opencv?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While OpenCV will work with essentially any USB webcam, there is a great deal of variety in image quality. I have personally had excellent luck with the [PS3 Eye Cam](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B000VTQ3LU) in Ubuntu after [removing the casing.](http://createdigitalmotion.com/2009/08/trick-out-your-ps3-eye-webcam-best-cam-for-vision-augmented-reality/) Even though it is only $25-50, it can run up to 125 Hz and is less susceptible to motion blur. I am not sure how the [open source Mac OS X drivers](http://sourceforge.net/projects/webcam-osx/files/) compare to the Linux drivers, but it is worth consideration.

Answer (score 2):

The internal webcam that comes with their laptop works quite well (rather high  quality). You can also get Logitech Orbit (I personally have rather good experience with those).

Comment: note that webcam quality varies wildly with the different models of laptop. For example, the new MBA has a far thinner screen bezel than any other model and so the webcam sensor has been seriously compromised to fit.